# TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Popen' Python

Tags: python, popen

I have these lines using Popen

```
numcpu = sub.Popen("($(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'physical id' | awk '{print $NF}' | sort | uniq | wc -l))", shell=True, stdout=sub.PIPE, stderr=sub.PIPE)
numcores = sub.Popen("($(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'cpu cores' | awk '{print $NF}' | sort | uniq | wc -l))", shell=True, stdout=sub.PIPE, stderr=sub.PIPE)  
numsibling = sub.Popen("($(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'siblings' | awk '{print $NF}' | sort | uniq | wc -l))", shell=True, stdout=sub.PIPE, stderr=sub.PIPE)
```

but run into this traceback error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./cputool", line 53, in <module>
CpuTool()
File "./cputool", line 45, in CpuTool
numthreads = int(numsibling)/int(numcores)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Popen'
```

On this line

```
numthreads = int(numsibling)/int(numcores)
```

I'm new to scripting is there anyway to assign these Popen values to a string or int so this works? I don't think doing a simple numcpu== 'anything' works but I could be wrong? Any help for a beginner? Nothing I can find on here (SO) for similar cases, work for my case unfortunately. Thanks!

Comment: you don't need subprocesses here. You can open the file in Python: `with open('/proc/cpuinfo') as file: parse(file)` or use a library that provides the same info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the stdout with [`proc_name.stdout.readline()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdout) and then convert it to `int`.

```
numthreads = int(numsibling.stdout.readline())/int(numcores.stdout.readline())
```

Comment: this fixes this current issue but leads to another traceback error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./cputool", line 49, in <module>
    CpuTool()
  File "./cputool", line 41, in CpuTool
    numthreads = int((numsibling.stdout.readline())/int(numcores.stdout.readline()))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
any solution for that? Thanks for the solution though.

Comment: @Klyde That's because of you output that is not a digit you can print `numsibling.stdout.readline()` to see that whats your result if it contains some extra characters like whitespace or dot or ... for example `3.` or `3\n` you can remove it by striping the string.

Comment: Im new to python so how would I strip it so it can be assigned as a digit? I dont need it printed out. I need to have those values do math and assign them to other ones. Thanks

Comment: @Klyde I mean print it to know that whats the out put but then you can strip it with `str.strip` method or replace the extra characters if they are inside the string for example `'47-34'.replace('-','')` or `'8764\n'.strip()` or `'83476#'.strip('#')`